# How to store JSP Web page data in XML Sheet

Tags: mysql, xml, jsp

How to store JSP Web page data in XML Sheet

Comment: that's not clear enough. please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ***castor mapping***.

For reference see [here](http://www.castor.org/xml-mapping.html).